# Is it possible to give meaning like transpose or continuity to matries involving differential operator entries?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra

Let $C^\infty(\mathbb{T}^3,\mathbb{R}^3)$ be the space of periodic smooth vector fields. Here, $\mathbb{T}^3$ is the $3$-dimensional torus.

Next, let $\partial_i$ be the partial differential operators on $\mathbb{R}^3$ with $i=1,2,3$.

Then, we can at least think of the following vector space :
\begin{equation}
V:=\Bigl\{ (a_{ 1i} \partial_i, a_{2 i'} \partial_{i'}, a_{ 3i''} \partial_{i''})^T \mid a_{ij} \in \mathbb{R} \text{ for all } i,j=1,2,3 \Bigr\}
\end{equation}
which is finite-dimensional if we take the basis elements to be $(\partial_i,0,0)^T, (0,\partial_{i'},0)^T, (0,0,\partial_{i''})^T$.

Here, the superscript $T$ means the transpose that turns a row vector into a column vector and vice versa; I do not consider any adjoint of the differential operator at all. (Also, I used the summation convention for brevity.)

Moreover, we can define a trilinear map $C^\infty(\mathbb{T}^3,\mathbb{R}^3) \times V \times C^\infty(\mathbb{T}^3,\mathbb{R}^3) \to C^\infty(\mathbb{T}^3,\mathbb{R}^3)$ given by
\begin{equation}
( v, A, w) \to v(x)[A^Tw](x)
\end{equation}
where I write vectors in the column as default. Again, I emphasize that $A^T$ just means $A$ in the row vector with the same entries.

Now, my questions are:

1. Is the above trilinear map continuous with respect to the Fréchet topology of $C^\infty(\mathbb{T}^3,\mathbb{R}^3)$ and the finite dimensional norm topology of $V$?
2. We can think of the linear map $v \in C^\infty(\mathbb{T}^3,\mathbb{R}^3) \to v^T \in C^\infty(\mathbb{T}^3,[\mathbb{R}^3]^*)$. Here, $[\mathbb{R}^3]^*$ is the dual space of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and thus the space of row vectors. If this linear map is applied to an element of the form $v(x)[A^Tw](x)$, is it correct to compute as follows?:
   \begin{equation}
   v(x)[A^Tw](x) \to w^T(x) [A v^T](x)
   \end{equation}

I am sorry for being somewhat lengthy and possibly not clear about my questions…but these issues seem quite subtle and hard to express for me…. Could anyone please clarify?